# creating file for shell output redirection

Tags: c++, c, shell, unix, redirect

This is a school assignment.

So basically I have written a C code for a shell that handles terminating the command with `&`, and input / output redirection using `>` or `<.` using pipes and `fork()`, `execvp()`.

The problem is my input/output redirection only handles that for files that *already exist*.

What i need to know is how would I go about redirecting output to a file that doesn't exist - I know I would have to create the file, but I'm not sure how that works.

For example: `ls -a < test.txt`

If test.txt is not in the directory, i need to create it and redirect output to that. 
So how do I create this file?

here is some basic example code which does not create a new file:

```
        else if( '>' ==  buff[i] ){
           i++;
           j=0;

           if( ' ' == buff[i] ) 
              i++;

           while( ' ' != buff[i] && i < len )
              out_file[j++]=buff[i++];
           out_file[j]='\0';


           if ( ( ofd = open(out_file,1) ) < 0 ){
              perror("output redirected file");
              exit( 1 );
           }

           close(1);
           dup(ofd);
        }
```

Any help with how I can output and create a new file would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Small technical note: did you mean `ls -a > test.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `open` to create the file, if necessary:

```
if ( ( ofd = open(out_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT) ) < 0 ) {
```

Note that your code will be more readable if you use the named constants for the flags to `open`. Compare with the functionally equivalent

```
if ( ( ofd = open(out_file, 513) ) < 0 ) {
```

or even

```
if ( ( ofd = open(out_file, 0x0201) ) < 0 ) {
```